# express - sendfile from subdirectory

Tags: express

I have a small express app where I want to send an image file.

This works:

```
const options = {
    root: __dirname,
    dotfiles: 'deny'
};

res.sendFile(`${req.params.articleId}.png`, options);
```

That doesn't work:

```
const options = {
    root: __dirname + '/images,
    dotfiles: 'deny'
};

res.sendFile(`${req.params.articleId}.png`, options);
```

Even with `path.resolve` or something. Somehow the image doesnt get send when I move the images to a subfolder of the project.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is the exact value of `req.params.articleId`?  What is the exact value of `__dirname` and is that the parent directory of your `images` sub-directory?  What platform are you running on?  Did you try: `root: path.join(__dirname, 'images'),`?  And, is the `images` directory directly below the directory where this module is located?

Answer (score 0):

To solve problems like this, you just need to do some debugging.

First, add this:

```
const rootDir = path.join(__dirname, "images");
console.log(rootDir);

const options = {
    root: rootDir,
    dotfiles: 'deny'
};

const filename = `${req.params.articleId}.png`;
console.log(filename);
res.sendFile(filename, options);
```

And, verify that `rootDir` and `filename` are indeed the directory and filename you want them to be.

---

If that still isn't working, then add this:

```
const filename = `${req.params.articleId}.png`;
console.log(filename);
const fullname = path.join(rootDir, filename);
console.log(`${fullname} exists: ${fs.existsSync(fullname)}`);
res.sendFile(filename, options);
```

---

If that doesn't show that fullname exists, then triple check your file paths and make sure that the file is indeed there.  Check file permissions.

If fullname exists, but `res.sendFile()` still doesn't work, try this:

```
const filename = `${req.params.articleId}.png`;
const fullname = path.join(rootDir, filename);
res.sendFile(fullname, options);
```

Which will just try to send it with a full path (not using the root setting at all).  If even this doesn't work, then the file must not be where you think it is or you don't have the right permissions to see it or read it.

Comment: @johnbraum - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.